# update mysql table with hibernate showing error

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, hql

In my Spring project I want to update mysql table field according to the url :

I have url below:

```
localhost:9191/access/name/article?key=xyz
```

I want to fetch the article from url and then update the status and article field of the corrsponding mysql table

In my database I have the table name "user".

```
user(stu_id,name,email,article,status)
```

mysql query is:

```
UPDATE user
SET article='null', status=true
WHERE article='xyz';  here xyz=user.getArticle()
```

To achieve this I have done the below

User.java is:

```
public User(String article, String status) {
        super();
        this.article = article;
        this.status = status;
    }
```

UserDao.java

```
public interface UserDao {


     public void updateUser(User user);

}
```

UserDaoImpl.java is:

```
@Transactional
@Repository("userDao")
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {
@Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public void updateUser(User user) {


        String hql = "update user set article = null,status=true" 
                +"where article=:key1";

        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql)
        .setParameter("key1", user.getArticle());
        }
    }
```

UserService.java is:

```
public interface UserService {

    User updateUser(String article, String status);

}
```

UserServiceImpl.java is:

```
@Service("userService")
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS)
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

public User updateUser(String article, String status) {


        User user = new User(article,status);


        userDao.updateUser(user);

        return user;

return user;
}
```

UserController.java is:

```
//localhost:9191/access/name/article?key=xyz 

@RequestMapping(value="/access/name/id", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String byParameter( User user, HttpServletRequest request) {

        boolean ps=true;
        String foo= request.getParameter("key");

        userService.updateUserinfo(foo, ps);


        return "signupLogin";
    }
```

but it is showing error:

```
ERROR [] (ErrorCounter.java:56) - line 1:51: unexpected token: key
ERROR [] (ErrorCounter.java:56) - line 1:58: unexpected token: =
```

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: node to traverse cannot be null!

```
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1760)
    at com.student.dao.UserDaoImpl.updateUser(UserDaoImpl.java:40)
    at com.student.service.UserServiceImpl.updateUserinfo(UserServiceImpl.java:66)
```

where is the problem?What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 1):

Make following correction into sql query use `User` in place of `user` into query.

```
String hql = "update User set article = null, status = true where article = :key1";
```

if you don't want to change this method then you can use `createSqlQuery` method in place of `createQuery` method .

this solution may be help.

Answer (score 0):

```
  at com.student.dao.UserDaoImpl.updateUser(UserDaoImpl.java:40)
```

you were executing the wrong query.you should do like below code:

```
@Transactional
@Repository("userDao")
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {
@Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public void updateUser(User user) {


        String hql = "update user set article = null,status=true" 
                +"where article=:key1";

        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(hql)
        .setParameter("key1", user.getArticle());
        }
    }
```

the syntax is like:
where **user**(this is the database table ) and **article,status** are the fields